# Bulk spring property values by prefix with one properties file

Tags: java, spring

Is possible in Spring properties to bulk some of them by prefix in properties class?

For example

**Property file**

```
a.property1=Some property
a.property2=Some property
b.property1=Some property
b.property2=Some property
```

**Properties class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class Properties{
   private String aProperty1 // this points to a.property1

   private String aProperty2 // this points to a.property2

   private String bProperty1 // this points to b.property1

   private String bProperty2 // this points to b.property2
}
```

The thing I want to achieve is this: I want to have property file holding items that have a lot of things in common **but i dont want to separate these properties in each file**. I need to have one property class where I can get all property values. Then I can, for example have one main property holding base URL of API I want to connect and just use a.property=@property.baseURL@/something

Surely, I could get rid of prefixes a have for example just aProperty1, bProperty etc. in .properties file but thats not what I exactly want and that would be solution if its not possible to easily make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Would this cover the requirements?

```
public class AppProperties
{
   private String property1;
   private String property2;

   public String getProperty1()
   {
      return property1;
   }

   public void setProperty1(String property1)
   {
      this.property1 = property1;
   }

   public String getProperty2()
   {
      return property2;
   }

   public void setProperty2(String property2)
   {
      this.property2 = property2;
   }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AppPropertiesBundle
{

   @Configuration
   @PropertySource(name = "PropsA", value = "classpath:app-props.properties")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "a")
   public static class A extends AppProperties
   {
   }

   @Configuration
   @PropertySource(name = "PropsB", value = "classpath:app-props.properties")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "b")
   public static class B extends AppProperties
   {
   }

}
```

Example `app-props.properties` file (on the classpath):

```
a.property1=a-prop1
a.property2=a-prop2

b.property1=b-prop1
b.property2=b-prop2
```

Usage:

```
...
import AppPropertiesBundle;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApp
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class, args);

      AppPropertiesBundle.A propsA = context.getBean(AppPropertiesBundle.A.class);
      System.out.println("a.property1=" + propsA.getProperty1());
      System.out.println("a.property2=" + propsA.getProperty2());

      AppPropertiesBundle.B propsB = context.getBean(AppPropertiesBundle.B.class);
      System.out.println("b.property1=" + propsB.getProperty1());
      System.out.println("b.property2=" + propsB.getProperty2());

      context.close();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create properties this way for example

```
endpoint.url.products=http://localhost:8080/products
endpoint.url.products.something=something
```

Have your single properties class as follows

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class CustomProperties {

    private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> endpoint;

    // getter and setter
}
```

To get `products` URL, you say `endpoint.get("url").get("products")`

Similarly, you can add other properties and map them in this class.
If you want to go with properties classes, it is recommended to create one per category.